# Java: MVC and anonymous class for Controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I have a question about MVC pattern. I’m trying to use it for **desktop** project (i.e. not for net application), using Java in IntelliJ IDEA.
I am trying to create Model, View and Controller, according to MVC pattern. My question is: is it safe to say that from Java’s point of view, marked methods are already serving as Controllers and there is actually no need to create an explicit Controller class as a separate class? Like this:

[image: Option 1]

Or do I have to have to create an explicit CalculatorController class, like this:

[image: Option 2]

Remember that my task is to preserve MVC patter, where tasks for M, V and C are clearly divided.
Of these 2 options, which one preserves MVC pattern? Only the second, or both equally?
Thank you!

Comment: The point of MVC is to keep the M separate from the V and separate from the C - if you couple them you miss a big advantage of having your C probably accessible by multiple Vs (i.e. JFrame with GUI and a WEB GUI later on)

Comment: @ochi Thank you! Well, as of now, I have a separate Controller for every View (maybe it's correct to call it Presenter then?) and not planning to use one C for multiple Vs

Comment: I am looking at the images again, are you considering the `actionListeners` to be `Controllers` ?

Comment: @ochi That seems to be the case. With "explicit" division between V and C, Controller is something that a Listener sends request (or information) to, as it's in 2nd picture: listener calls for Controller to notify it about button being pressed, and Controller calls for Model to manipulate data accordingly. In the 1st picture, a Listener calls for Model without anything being between them, thus in a sense, a Listener is a kind of Controller, and it is a separate class (simply anonymous, but still separate, as MVC pattern dictates). Well, I understand it like this, at least.

Comment: Separating the listener from the controller gives you flexibility.  Today, you might be talking to a backend that connects to a DB. Tomorrow your data might come from a REST service (a file or other data source) - if you put all that data-fetching in the listener (pretending it is a controller, which is not) then when the backend changes, you need to change *all* your listeners (a lot of re-work) - Instead, if your controller changes a backend (and you are using interfaces) you only need to change the places that touch the backend, the rest of the app continues to work w/o modifications.

Comment: @ochi I see, that indeed makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Second option**

If you use your Controllers as Anonymous inner classes, how are you going to test your controller layer? If you don't separate your controllers, you won't be able to mock then for testing purposes.

Even if you don't want you write tests, the first option is going to create a really hard coupling between the Views and the Controller. There is no separation at all!

Prefer to explicitly create your controllers and create the interfaces for then before implementation. It will make TDD a lot easier, and you will also make a better code design in your project.

But remember, it's just my opinion. Always study to make sure that your project decision are correct and working for you.

Take a look in this article, it has a very simple implementation of the pattern: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm

**Edit**

**Let's compare both approaches.**

1. *Testability*

**Inner classes**: You can't test the control layer. All your controllers are anonymous inner classes. So you don't have access to then, making it impossible to test. In the MCV architecture it's really important to test your controllers. Conclusion: Really bad for testing.

**Explicitly classes**:  You can mock the view and the model so you can test the controllers. Same logic goes when testing the View and the Model. Conclusion: Easy to test.

2. *Maintainability*

**Inner classes**: All your controller logic are inside you anonymous inner classes (or lambdas). Trust me, you don't want that. All the complexity your app will be inside a class that was not meant to get big. A simple example:

```
//I need to get the people older than 50 years old, present to the user and wait for a click. If the list is empty, do something, if it's not do something else.

      buttonRefresh.onClickListener(() -> {
          List<Person> people = model.requestPeople();

          people = people.stream()
                      .filter(p -> p.getAge > 50) 
                      .collect(Collectors.toList())

          [code to create an adapter]

          if(people.isEmpty()){
             [do something...]
          } else{
             [do something else...]
          }

      })
```

This is a really simple code and it already getting confusing. What if I have another lambda inside my if and else?? The more your code gets bigger inside a anonymous inner classes, the worse. Conclusion: This is bad for maintainability because your code is going to grow in the wrong place.

**Explicitly classes**: You code can grow inside a class. You can add dependencies there, create methods, have inner classes...

3. *Separation of responsibilities*

**Inner classes**: There's no controller layer, to be true. All the controller code is inside your View classes, so the View and the Controller and basically the same classes. As a result your are going to have a really huge View classes with a lot of messy code. Conclusion: Bad, almost all the code of your application is going to be in the View classes.

**Explicitly classes**: The controller and the View have a very clear separation. Your view will have only methods for updating the view.

(I know you are going to create a lot of methods with basically 1-3 lines of code in the view classes. But it is better than huge methods with view and control logic in the same place.)

This is what I think. But you can always try both approaches and compare results!

Comment: Thank you for you advide! Yes, I did already study the article you pointed to, and I have tried it as well. Well, the reason I'm asking my question is that when I implement "implicit" controllers, it gives me 2 advantages:

Comment: first, it produces less code, and second, it eliminates the need for V and C to constantly exchange information and, moreover, the need for V to have a ton of "change-this-thing" methods. For example, if a button is pressed, a label needs to change its text. With implicit controller I can change it "on the fly". With explicit one, I have to: 1) create method "changeLabelText" in V 2) Notify controller that button is pressed 3) Call changeLabelText from Controller.

Comment: This way it seems that the View will have a ton of methods for various event and GUI elements property changes, whereas with implicit controller I can do all of this on the fly, without need for additional methods.

Comment: About your Edit -> OK, now I understand, thank you! Exaclty, I was thinking "with explicitly classes I'm going to have a TON of small "GuiElement1.setValue(blah)" methods in my Views, or a maybe a bunch of getters-setters and then a ton of using said getters-setters in Controller". But if many little methods in a View are better than an oversized View class, plus if it provides better testability and maintainability, I should go for it.

Comment: upvoted on separation of responsibilities - huge one in my books :)